# How can I use 10 folds cross validation in Stanford relation extraction (custom relation extraction model)

Tags: stanford-nlp, jnlp, opennlp, sharpnlp

How can I use 10 folds cross validation in Stanford relation extraction. I created a custom relation extraction model ,and I need to evaluate this model

Answer (score 0):

You may find [`CrossValidator`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/38b3976c8992383a4c6390d9b6019e868a93189d/src/edu/stanford/nlp/classify/CrossValidator.java) useful, if you're using the Stanford classifier. Taking a dataset, you can do something like:

```
Dataset dataset = ...;
double aveAccuracy = new CrossValidator(dataset, 10).computeAverage( (train, dev) -> {
  // train on |train| for the fold
  LinearClassifier classifier = ...;
  // evaluate on |dev| for the fold
  return classifier.evaluateAccuracy(dev);
});
```